# Trouble understanding output Recurse package

Tags: r, date, recursion, interpretation

I'm trying to analyse revisiting patterns using the new Recurse package (2018). 
The  R package ‘recurse’  calculates revisitations to locations in the movement trajectory or other locations for one or multiple individuals. The package also calculates metrics such as residence time and time between visits. It can be used to quantitatively identify frequently used sites (e.g. dens, nests, foraging locations), to examine patterns of revisitation. A circle of radius R is drawn around each point in the trajectory. The number of revisits is calculated
as the number of segments of the trajectory passing through that circle.

All works well, but I have trouble understanding the output. I've put examples of my input(dataframe) and output below. I think to understand that visitIdx is the number of time it is they entered the specific point. My input dates are in the year 2018, but for a reason I don't understand, I get output times around the year 1970. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong? Lastly, I don't see in what unity timeSinceLastVisit is given.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recurse/recurse.pdf

my simple code

```
# load trajectory data (routes)
data <- Unites.Trajectory.for.revisitation.analysis

# get recursions with radius of 35 m
library(recurse)

recursion35 <- getRecursions(x=data, radius=35, threshold = 0,timeunits = c("hours"), verbose = TRUE)

revisitation35 <- recursion35$revisitStats
```

Head of my input (dataframe):

```
X       Y         Timestamp     Focal group
601019  1933332 2018-02-19 08:26:00 UNITES
600998  1933335 2018-02-19 08:33:00 UNITES
600998  1933335 2018-02-19 12:03:00 UNITES
600984  1933311 2018-02-19 12:09:20 UNITES
600972  1933297 2018-02-19 12:15:40 UNITES
600954  1933301 2018-02-19 12:22:00 UNITES
600954  1933301 2018-02-19 13:13:00 UNITES
600949  1933298 2018-02-19 13:17:00 UNITES
```

Head of output:

```
      id    x        y  coordIdx visitIdx   entranceTime    exitTime    timeInside  timeSinceLastVisit
1   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   1   31-12-1969 18:00    31-12-1969 18:00    0.00076523  NA
2   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   2   31-12-1969 18:00    31-12-1969 18:00    0.000659302 0.01235843
3   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   3   31-12-1969 18:01    31-12-1969 18:01    0.00093708  0.003822967
4   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   4   31-12-1969 18:04    31-12-1969 18:04    0.001767337 0.061540719
5   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   5   31-12-1969 18:05    31-12-1969 18:05    -0.000600144    0.005804636
6   UNITES  601019  1933332 1   6   31-12-1969 18:05    31-12-1969 18:05    0.002684722 0.003184358
```

Comment: What is `class(data$Timestamp)` ? Also in your call to `getRecursions` you need to supply a single value for `timeunits`, e.g., `timeunits="hours"` which is the default and should then be the units for the `timeSinceLastVisit` output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thank you for your reply. my class is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Thank you for the timeunit tip! I better understand how to interpret the data now, but the problem of the dates being 50 years back in time isn't solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to convert your Timestamp field into a datetime class before running the `getRecursions` function

`data$Timestamp<-as.POSIXct(data$Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`